# "Take your change for / from / on your $100" - Which preposition should I use?

Tags: prepositions, word-in-context

> - "Here's the change back for / from / on your hundred"
> - "How much change do I get for / from / on a $100 note?"
> - "I doubt I have change for / from / on $100"

Which prepositions are correct to use?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest:

> Here's the change from your hundred (dollar bill/note)

NOT **the change BACK...**

> How much change do/would I get from $100 (note)?

and

> I doubt I have change for $100.